# php return field names of an odbc_exec query

Tags: php, sql, odbc

I'm using odbc_exec to execute sql.  It returns the results fine, but I would like to get an array of the sql field names.  I have them in the SQL, obviously, but I need a programmatic way to quickly return them from a query

```
$sql = "SELECT  mv_value, mv_entered_by, mv_student_id, mc_module_id, mc_type
                FROM MarkbookValue t1
                RIGHT JOIN MarkbookColumn t2 ON t1.mv_column_id = t2.mc_id
            WHERE DateDiff(minute, mc_date_entered, '" . $date . "') = 0
                AND mc_entered_by = '" . $name . "' ";
```

Running it through:

```
     $result = odbc_exec(CONN, $sql);
```

I'd like to get an array listing:

```
     mv_value, mv_entered_by, mv_student_id, mc_module_id, mc_type
```

so I can then output a CSV with headings

Comment: currently just typing them out one by one... I'm looking to automate a lot of CSV writing

Comment: Add some relevant code please:)

Comment: added some, hopefully that'll help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a hack, is there a more elegant solution?

```
$result = odbc_exec($server, $sql);

$fp = fopen($name, 'w');

while ($export = odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (!isset($headings))
    {
        $headings = array_keys($export);
        fputcsv($fp, $headings, ',', '"');
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $export, ',', '"');
}
fclose($fp);
```